# AWS SageMaker XGBoost multi classification algorithm and num_class hyper parameter error

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, xgboost

I have a .csv file that contains a dataset I want to use with XGBoost and SageMaker. The
structure of the data.csv file has 7 columns. L1,L2,L3,L4,L5,L6,Type. The "Type" column has 5 types of strings that I will use to classify the inferences.
Here is my data transformation and its results:

```py
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
le = LabelEncoder()
data_r['Type'] = le.fit_transform(data_r['Type'])
data_r['Type']
0      4
1      4
2      4
3      4
....
300    0
301    0
...
1983   3
....
2300   2
2600   1
```

As you can see the categorial feature was encoded with values 0,1,2,3,4
I now move it to the first column:

```py
data_r = data_r[['Type', 'L1', 'L2', 'L3', 'L4', 'L5', 'L6' ]] 
data_r.head()
    Type,    L1,     L2,    L3,   L4,   L5,    L6   
0      4      1      45     32    19    -3     8
1      4     34      95     -45    9     2     45
2      4      0       5     -3    27    -2     1     
3      4     10      15     -13    7     0     38 
4      4.     78      1      0     43    45    57
```

I then split the data into train, validation, and test, and upload it to S3.
I also have a valid session and xgb estimator. I then create  the hyperparameters as under:

```py
xgb.set_hyperparameters(
                        max_depth=5,
                        eta=0.2,
                        gamma=4,
                        min_child_weight=6,
                        subsample=0.8,
                        objective='multi:softmax',
                        num_class=4,
                        early_stopping_rounds=10,
                        num_round=100
)
```

But I get the error :

```
SoftMaxMultiClassObj: label must be in [0, num_class).
```

What is wrong with this code or data transformation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The upper limit in `[0, num_class)` is excluded, so your hyperparameter should be `num_class=5`, so labels `[0,5) -> 0,1,2,3,4`.